# since redis is single-threaded, then our concurrent requests become serialized requests when accessing redis. What is the significance of using redis?

Tags: redis

We usually use redis for caching in the Spring‘s project. My problem is that since redis is single-threaded, then our concurrent requests become serialized requests when accessing redis. then,what is the significance of using redis?

Is it only because of "It's not very frequent that CPU becomes your bottleneck with Redis, as usually Redis is either memory or network bound.
......
using pipelining Redis running on an average Linux system can deliver even 1 million requests per second......
"?

I am learning redis， [Redis document FAQ](https://redis.io/topics/faq)

Answer (score 0):

You've basically asked two questions in one question:

> > What is the significance of using Redis.

Well, Redis is known to be fast because it keeps the data in memory. If you ask whether being a single-threaded application is very restrictive - well, its a product, that works like this by design, maybe it could be even more performant if it was multithreaded, it depends on actual implementation under the hood after all.

In any case, it offers much more than just a "get data in memory": 
 - Many primitives to work with
 - Configurable persistence
 - Replication of data 
And much more

If the question is whether the in-memory cache will be faster (you've mentioned Spring framework, so you're at Java Land) - then yes.

In fact, Spring Cache support Guava Cache (spring 5/spring boot 2 use Caffeine for the same purpose instead) - and yes it will be faster in a head-to-head comparison with Redis. But what if you have a distributed application with many instances and one instance calculated something and put it to cache, how do you get the same information from another instance without distributing the information between the instances. Well, there are tools like Hazelcast but it's out of scope for this question, the point is that when the application is beyond basic, the tasks like cache synchronization /keeping it up-to-date becomes much less obvious.

> > If you can deliver 1 million operations per second.

Now this question is too vague to answer:

- What is the hardware that runs Redis?
- What are the network configurations? (after all Redis calls are done over the network)
- How often do you persist on disk (Redis has configurations for that)
- Do you use replication and split the load between many Redis servers reaching an overall much faster throughput?
- What commands exactly are being running under that hood?

In any case, when it comes to benchmarking you can set up your system in the option way and use the tool offered by Redis itself:

[Redis Benchmarking Chapter in Redis tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)

The tool is called `redis-benchmark` you can run it with various parameters and see how fast redis really is:

Here is an example (I encourage you to read the full article in the link):

```
$ redis-benchmark -t set,lpush -n 100000 -q
  SET: 74239.05 requests per second
  LPUSH: 79239.30 requests per second
```

This says: Connect to redis server available on localhost, run (-n) 100000 requests in a quiet mode (-q parameter) and run only tests specific for two commands: set and lpush